# How to anchor different things based on a property?

Tags: qt, qml, anchorpoint

I desire a QML layout that looks something like this:

```
+--------+            +--------+
|        |            |        |
| Text 1 |            | Text 3 |
+--------+            +--------+
----^^---------vv---------^^----
           +--------+
           | Text 2 |
           |        |
           +--------+
```

In other words, alternate objects (a QML Item in this case) are placed above or below some central line and the things they contain (QML Text) *within* those objects need to go to either the top or the bottom of the object.

Now I know I can align specific things with anchors on the items:

```
anchors.bottom: isAbove ? parent.bottom : parent.top;
```

but that will set the item bottom anchor regardless of whether it's needed (such as with the second object above containig `Text 2`).

What I'm actually looking for is a way to set only *one* anchor depending on the position. In psuedo-QML, that would be:

```
isAbove? (anchors.bottom: parent.bottom) : (anchors.top: parent.top);
```

In other words, I only want to anchor the item bottom to parent bottom if it's above the line. Otherwise I want to anchor the item top to the parent top.

I thought it *may* be something like:

```
anchors.bottom: isAbove ? parent.bottom : nothing   ;
anchors.top:    isAbove ? nothing       : parent.top;
```

but `nothing` does not appear to be an anchoring option :-)

Is there a way to do this with QML?

Comment: change `nothing` to `undefined`

Comment: @eyllanesc: You're kidding me, right, it's *that* simple? :-)

Comment: Did it work? I have not tested it

Comment: @eyllanesc: it surely does work. Thanks heaps. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept, and hopefully future searchers will be helped as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an anchor you must use `undefined` as indicated by the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#changing-anchors)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `States` mechanism and use `AnchorChanges`, see https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-anchorchanges.html for a good example